# Navigation_Failed when pass string value between pages in windows phone C#

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8

I want to pass string value from setting.xaml to MainPage.xaml

Here's my code 
**settings.xaml**

```
Public settings(){
.....
string url = string.Format("/MainPage.xaml?msg1={0}", updateSignature.Text);
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(url, UriKind.Relative));}
```

my update.Signature is a textblock

This is my code in **MainPage.xaml**

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
            string msg1 = "";
            if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("msg1", out msg1))
            {
                textBlock1.Text = String.Format("Signature Anda :{0}", msg1);
            }
```

When i build it and move to settings page, i got Navigation_Failed error . What should i do ?

Comment: Do you mean NavigationFailed event or an exception?  If it's an exception, please provide the details of the exception.  If it's the event, please provide the details of the Exception property on the event args.  Without those we can only guess at the problem--which isn't particular helpful to you.

Comment: whenever i go to settings page i thrown to RootFrame_NavigationFailed. But now , fourtunately, i have solved this problem. I didn't notice that i used NavigationService not in appropriate way . Thank you btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code in SettingsPage.xaml seems to be in constructor. It's not the proper way of doing this. I couldn't get your problem what exactly it is, but i can provide you solution in simple way. My code in settings page.xaml is,

```
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Name="updateSignature" Text="textinSettingsPage" FontSize="30"/>
        <Button Content="GotoMainPage" Click="Button_Click"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

I handled this using button click. And this is my code in SettingsPage.xaml.cs file,

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string url = string.Format("/MainPage.xaml?msg1={0}", updateSignature.Text);
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(url, UriKind.Relative));
    }
```

And this is code in MainPage.xaml,

```
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Name="textBlock1" FontSize="30"/>
        <Button Content="Go to settings page" Click="settings_Click" Name="settings"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

Finally my code is MainPage.xaml.cs,

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        string msg1 = "";
        if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("msg1", out msg1))
        {
            textBlock1.Text = String.Format("Signature Anda :{0}", msg1);
        }
    }

    private void settings_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/SettingsPage.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
    }
```

Comment: oh God, my mistake to put NavigationService in that constructor, 
Now i have Home button and backPressed Event handling to Handle that NavigationService. And now , it's work !
Oh , my next question, how can i use that new string value in other method on my MainPage ?

Comment: Thank you , i have resolve all of my problem above and now fit my scenario.